# ffmpeg usage in Android Studio

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to use ffmpeg sources in Android Studio under Windows10.
I built the ffmpeg.3.3.3 under ubuntu on Virtual Box by the followinf script and integrated the sources into Android Studio project:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/etc/FFmpegOnAndroid/android-ndk-r14b
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64
TOOLCHAIN=/etc/FFmpegOnAndroid/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPU=arm
PREFIX=/etc/FFmpegOnAndroid/ffmpeg-3.3.3/output
ADDI_CFLAGS="-fomit-frame-pointer"
function build_one
{
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --enable-shared \
        --disable-static \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-symver \
        --enable-small \
        --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android- \
        --target-os=linux \
        --arch=x86_64 \
        --enable-cross-compile \
        --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
        --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
        --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make
    make install
}
build_one
```

When I execute the following command under ubuntu, the output file is created without losing the quality:

```
ffmpeg -i sample_2.mp4 -i ic_launcher.jpg -filter_complex [1:v]scale=70:-1[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[out] -map 0:a? -map [out] output.mp4
```

but when I call `main()` function of ffmpeg.c in Android studio with same arguments, the quality of output file is lost.

Here are the difference of info of created output files:

Android Studio:

```
Stream #0:1(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1200x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 585 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
```

ubuntu:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1200x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 423 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Sargis Boyajyan

Comment: On Ubuntu, you didn't build **ffmpeg**, did you? If you check teh available codecs, you will find that the Linux version was built with x264 encoder, while for Android, you did not include this library.

Comment: Hi Alex Cohn, thank you for response. I build ffmpeg on ubuntu by script attached above. When I get list of codecs by using av_codec_next(NULL) API in android studio project, I sow h264 in that list, also I sow h264 in formats list(if this doesn't mean that ffmpeg is built with x264?). When output stream is created, the default format is MPEG4. When I run the ffmpeg executable of the same build on ubuntu, the default format is h264. Where could be the difference?

Comment: My bad. I asked about ffmpeg *for* Ubuntu. I understand that you cross-compiled ffmpeg for Android on the same machine. Concerning x264, your script does not enable it. h264 *decoder* is on by default, but the h264 *encoder* is a separate library, and comes under a different (GPL) license (which may or may not be a concern for you).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand, I will try to compile ffmpeg with libx264.

Comment: Thank you Alex Cohn, after I built ffmpeg with libx264, everything worked properly. I appreciate your help a lot.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

To enable h264 encoder, you should build ffmpeg with x86 (which is not the default configuration). On the other hand, h264 decoder is an organic part of ffmpeg, and is included by default. Note that the x86 library has different licensing than most of ffmpeg.